# GitHub installation on package 'MazamaScience/RAWSmet'

Tags: r, git, github, installation, package

Here is the GitHub site for the package: https://github.com/MazamaScience/RAWSmet.
I used devtools::install_github('MazamaScience/RAWSmet') and got the error message:

```
> devtools::install_github('MazamaScience/RAWSmet')
Downloading GitHub repo MazamaScience/RAWSmet@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\ygrund\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaUK4eB\remotes2c14665e277e\MazamaScience-RAWSmet-bced3ce/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'RAWSmet': (536ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (352ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'RAWSmet_0.2.4.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/ygrund/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'RAWSmet' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: object 'US_stateCodeToName' is not exported by 'namespace:MazamaSpatialUtils'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'RAWSmet'
* removing 'C:/Users/ygrund/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RAWSmet'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/ygrund/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/RAWSmet'
Error: Failed to install 'RAWSmet' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/ygrund/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpaUK4eB/file2c1440477e33/RAWSmet_0.2.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't understand what is wrong here. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you open the github issue as well: https://github.com/MazamaScience/RAWSmet/issues/50. You should probably wait for the author to fix the package. They are trying to import a function from another package but that function doesn't exist. Seems like a lot of work is being done on the package in the last few days.

Comment: Yes. I did. :-D The author has replied. Thanks @MrFlick.